# Expanding isospin symmetry to $SU(3)$ flavor symmetry for Baryon octet diagram

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, isospin-symmetry, baryons

Let's consider about the Baryon octet diagram. We can identify the isospin $I_3$ symmetry by noticing the mirror symmetry with respect to the $I_3$, i.e. x-axis. However, how can we expand this into $SU(3)$ flavor symmetry? How is this represented in the octet diagram?

Comment: As a note, is it related to the representation of the generators of $SU(3)$? Or, if that is not the case, is it related to the root system of $SU(3)$?

Comment: Yes. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)#Baryon_octet)  and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon#Isospin_and_charge)  and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Representations_of_the_SU(3)_group).  Can you sharpen your question using this standard language?

Comment: Related : [Symmetry in terms of matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353986/).