# Youngs' tableau method and its relation with tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, quarks

During my masters my prof. mentioned that the Youngs' tableau method can be used to calculate the **number independent components of any arbitrary rank symmetric tensor in arbitrary dimensions**. I wasn't much familiar with the concepts of Youngs tableau method back then. Now I am reading those methods and can't understand how they can be used to calculate the number of independent components of a symmetric tensor. Can anyone explain this concept or suggest a book or article to understand this in details?

Update after the comment:
Suppose we have a completely symmetric rank 3 tensor in 4 dimensions, can you show how many independent components it would require. I know about the formulae to obtain this number using combinatorics. But I want to do it using Youngs’ tableau.

Comment: Related : [Symmetry in terms of matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353986/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I read your answer but I am still struggling to understand it completely. I have updated my question, can you write a detailed answer please.

Comment: My answer in above link doesn't answer your question using Youngs’ tableau.

Comment: From your answer I got the idea that, in Youngs tableau each box can be treated as an index of a tensor and the number of quantum states can be treated as the no. of values each index can take. Using this I got answer 20 for my above question. Is it correct?

Comment: Exactly for the number 20 :  The independent components of a completely symmetric rank $\:p=3\:$ tensor in $\:d=4\:$ dimensions is
\begin{equation}
N\!\left(p,d\right)=\binom{p\!+\!d\!-\!1}{d\!-\!1} 
\tag{N-04}\label{N-04} 
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
N\!\left(3,4\right)=\binom{3\!+\!4\!-\!1}{4\!-\!1}=\binom{6}{3}=20 
\tag{N-04'}\label{N-04'}  
\end{equation}
We say that the tensor is of dimension $\:N=20$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The independent components of a tensor whose symmetry type is given by a given Young diagram each correspond to a [semistandard tableau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux) with that same shape.  And the number of semistandard tableaux for a given Young diagram can be found via a [hook length formula:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula#Semi-standard_tableaux_hook_length_formula)
$$
N = \prod_{(i,j) \in \lambda} \frac{ k - i + j}{h_\lambda(i,j)}
$$
where (using the English conventions for Young diagrams)

- $k$ is the range of entries allowed in the tableau (in your case, the dimension of the underlying vector space)
- $i$ and $j$ are the index of the row and column, respectively (numbered starting from the top left, beginning with 1)
- $h_\lambda(i,j)$ is the *hook length* associated with the cell $(i,j)$;  it is found by counting all the cells that are directly below the cell $(i,j)$ and all the cells that are directly to the right of $(i,j)$, and adding 1 for the cell itself. In other words, if you draw a line that comes from below the diagram, hits $(i,j)$, and then "hooks" to the right and exits the diagram, $h_\lambda(i,j)$ is the number of cells you passed through.

So, for a general $k$ and a Young diagram consisting of three cells in a single row, this becomes
$$
N = \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 1 + 1}{3} \right)}_{(i,j) = (1,1)} \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 1 + 2}{2} \right)}_{(i,j) = (1,2)} \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 1 + 3}{1} \right)}_{(i,j) = (1,3)} = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}
$$
which gives $N = 20$ when $k = 4$, as you found.

As another example, for the mixed-symmetry Young diagram with three cells, we have
$$
N = \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 1 + 1}{3} \right)}_{(i,j) = (1,1)} \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 1 + 2}{1} \right)}_{(i,j) = (1,2)} \underbrace{\left( \frac{k - 2 + 1}{1} \right)}_{(i,j) = (2,1)} = \frac{k(k+1)(k-1)}{3}.
$$
(This also happens to yield $N = 20$ when $k = 4$, but this is just a coincidence;  for general $k$, the dimensionality of this representation is different.)

Comment: thanks for the insight.