# On the quark composition of baryons

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, isospin-symmetry, baryons

Baryons are made of three quarks, in the form $\vert qqq \rangle$. If we consider just the isospin doublet $u$ and $d$,  there are 8 total possibilities:

[image]

Now, the first 4 are respectively $\Delta^{++}, \Delta^+, \Delta^0$ and $ \Delta^-$. But what about the other 4?

Comment: Recall $|p_\uparrow\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt {18}} [ 2| u_\uparrow d_\downarrow u_\uparrow \rangle + 2| u_\uparrow  u_\uparrow d_\downarrow \rangle +2| d_\downarrow u_\uparrow   u_\uparrow \rangle - | u_\uparrow u_\downarrow d_\uparrow\rangle  -| u_\uparrow d_\uparrow u_\downarrow\rangle  -| u_\downarrow d_\uparrow u_\uparrow\rangle  
-| d_\uparrow u_\downarrow u_\uparrow\rangle  -| d_\uparrow  u_\uparrow u_\downarrow\rangle   -| u_\downarrow u_\uparrow d_\uparrow\rangle   ]$

Comment: I'm sorry sir, what's the meaning of those arrows?

Comment: Spin. Both iso and spin symmetries are mixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In OP's table the first 4 rows (=the isospin quadruplet) are the [$\Delta$ particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon), which sit inside a spin-$3/2$ $uds$ [baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon#Isospin_and_charge) decuplet.
2. The 4th and 3rd last rows are the [proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton#Quarks_and_the_mass_of_a_proton) and neutron, respectively, which form an [isospin duplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleon), and which sit inside a spin-$1/2$ $uds$ [baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon#Isospin_and_charge) octet.
3. The last 2 rows (=the second isospin duplet) are absent in the standard model, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61575/2451) related Phys.SE post.